How to pass -grpc flag on Android Studio
I'm using Android Studio on WSL and getting this error

the console show the log
2024-09-30 17:01:21,678 [    654]   WARN - #c.i.s.ComponentManagerImpl - com.android.tools.idea.flags.StudioFlags <clinit> requests com.android.tools.idea.flags.StudioFlagSettings instance. Class initialization must not depend on services. Consider using instance of the service on-demand instead.
2024-09-30 17:01:22,024 [   1000]   WARN - #c.i.n.i.NotificationGroupManagerImpl - Notification group Logcat is already registered (group=com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup@2dc8f558). Plugin descriptor: PluginDescriptor(name=Android, id=org.jetbrains.android, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=/snap/android-studio/161/plugins/android, version=241.15989.150.2411.11948838, package=null, isBundled=true)
2024-09-30 17:01:25,870 [   4846]   WARN - #com.android.ddmlib - * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
2024-09-30 17:01:27,620 [   6596]   WARN - #c.i.u.j.JBCefApp - JCefAppConfig.class is not from a JBR module, url: jar:file:/snap/android-studio/161/lib/lib.jar!/com/jetbrains/cef/JCefAppConfig.class (Use JBR bundled with the IDE)
2024-09-30 17:01:28,259 [   7235]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 8 API VanillaIceCream - Using fallback path for the emulator registration directory.
2024-09-30 17:01:28,259 [   7235]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 8 API VanillaIceCream - The emulator now requires a signed jwt token for gRPC access! Use the -grpc flag if you really want an open unprotected grpc port
2024-09-30 17:01:28,264 [   7240]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 8 API VanillaIceCream - *** Basic token auth should only be used by android-studio ***
2024-09-30 17:01:28,269 [   7245]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 8 API VanillaIceCream - Using fallback path for the emulator registration directory.
2024-09-30 17:01:28,872 [   7848]   WARN - #com.android.ddmlib - * daemon started successfully
2024-09-30 17:01:35,477 [  14453]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 8 API VanillaIceCream - Emulator terminated with exit code 139
2024-09-30 17:01:36,087 [  15063]   WARN - #com.android.sdklib.deviceprovisioner.DeviceAction - The emulator process for AVD Pixel_8_API_VanillaIceCream has terminated.
com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener$EmulatorTerminatedException: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_8_API_VanillaIceCream has terminated.
        at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener$WaitForEmulatorTask.run(EmulatorConnectionListener.java:93)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.RwLockHolder$executeOnPooledThread$1.run(RwLockHolder.kt:154)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:702)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:699)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:699)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

I guess the error is related "The emulator now requires a signed jwt token for gRPC access! Use the -grpc flag if you really want an open unprotected grpc port" so I guess I should pass this flag.
How can I pass this flag to the emulator?
Some observations:

I'm using a corporate notebook with windows; I'm having some issues with certs while using WSL

I have 200GB+ free space (since some entries seams to point this as the source issue)


